# SQL trigger to decrement another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've created a Database for a DVD store which contains a Film table to hold info about films + copies available, and a sale table. I've created sequences for the Film and Sale table, to auto-increment the Primary keys FILM_ID and SALE_TRANSACTION_REF respectively, using the following code.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Film_Seq
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOCACHE;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER New_Film 
BEFORE INSERT ON FILM 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
SELECT Film_Seq.NEXTVAL
INTO   :new.FILM_ID
FROM   dual;
END;
/
```

This seems to work handy enough, but when I try to use a trigger to decrement the COPIES_AVAILABLE attribute of the film in Film after a sale with the following code, I get an error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER After_Sale 
AFTER INSERT ON SALE 
DECLARE
ID NUMBER(38) := Sale_Seq.CURRVAL;
BEGIN
    UPDATE FILM
    SET COPIES_AVAILABLE = COPIES_AVAILABLE - 1
    FROM FILM, SALE
    WHERE FILM.FILM_ID = SALE.FILM_ID 
    AND (SALE.SALE_TRANSACTION_REF = ID);
END;
/
```

I actually get two errors, the first one relates to the declare statement, which is

```
4/2    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

And the second one has to do with the UPDATE statement and it is

```
6/2    PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I've wrecked my brains trying to construct this statement differently, and have searched the documentation but can't seem to find the answer, and help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, looking over my question it may not be obvious but I have already created a sale_seq.

Sorry, it may not be evident what I am trying to achieve here. Whenever a Film is sold and added to the sale table, I want to automatically decrement the Copie_Available for the corresponding film in the film table, so if I left out the AND `AND (SALE.SALE_TRANSACTION_REF = Sale_Seq.CURRVAL)` clause the trigger will complie grand, but will decrement all copies available for all films in the film table, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER After_Sale 
AFTER INSERT ON SALE 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE FILM
    SET COPIES_AVAILABLE = COPIES_AVAILABLE - 1
    WHERE FILM.FILM_ID = :NEW.FILM_ID
END;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, this is actually remarkably close to my original attempt but unfortunately this leads to SALE.SALE_TRANSACTION_REF being flagged as an invalid identifier, which is I assume because we haven't specified that we are using the Sale table in this trigger? As when I remove the AND clause it makes sale.film_id as an invalid identifier also?!

Comment: I update my answer to use `NEW.FILM_ID` at the place of `SALE.FILM_ID`. but I don't understand why do you need this: `AND (SALE.SALE_TRANSACTION_REF = (SELECT Sale_Seq.CURRVAL FROM DUAL));` doesn't make sense, or something I am not understanding @Dobhaweim

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify the desired functionality of the code. Sorry it was not clear.

Comment: @Dobhaweim why do you think it will decrement all films by 1 when you're telling it `WHERE FILM.FILM_ID = :NEW.FILM_ID` it will only decrement that film id. In all cases your `AND ...` is comparing 2 things that are surely `=` so if it works it will always return true

Comment: Sorry CodeBird I'm not 100% familiar with the construct NEW.FILM_ID, what is that specifying? Let's say we sell a copy of jaws with Film_ID of 1046, and there was 200 more films added to the film table after jaws  with the Film_ID extending therefore to 1246, what does NEW.FILM_ID actually point to?

Comment: @Dobhaweim you're telling oracle, that when you insert into sale, run this trigger. `:NEW.anything` refers to that column newly inserted into `SALE`. so here in your case `:NEW.FILM_ID` will return the `FILM_ID` that was just inserted into SALE table which is the `FILM_ID` you sold

Comment: I didn't know that was even possible, thanks so much, and for explaining it to me also, I really appreciate it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50065/discussion-between-dobhaweim-and-codebird)

Answer (score 0):

Why save COPIES_AVAILABLE  to your database. Why wouldn't you detract for instance [all copies in stock] - [all sold copies] if you want to know available copies.